# Add Div around dynamic html list content

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic-content

for example I have structure like this:

```
<Ul>
<div>heading</div>
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
<div>heading</div>
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
</Ul>
```

here content is dynamic where i need to add wrapper div around `heading` and followed content, something like this

```
<div class="wrap">
<div>heading</div>
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a DIV to wrap around your LIs consider adding a class to each LI that you want to appear as a heading.

```
<style>
.heading
{
 font-weight:bold;
}
</style>

<Ul>
<li class="heading">heading</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li class="heading">heading</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
</Ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is incorrect markup
ul tags can only contain li tags as direct children

```
<Ul>
<li><div>heading</div></li>//Enclose in an li tag
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li><div>heading</div></li>//Enclose in an li tag
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
</Ul>
```

or even

```
<div>heading</div>
<Ul>
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
</Ul>
```

Edit:

To wrap this inside a container

```
<div class="wrap">
<div>heading</div>
<Ul>
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
<li>dynamic content</li>
</Ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree with you whatever given Example here is complete dynamic.... I really appreciate.... Thanks

Comment: Post exactly what you are trying to do. Just the markup won't suffice

Comment: As you said I have changed something like this:     <Ul>
    <li>Heading</li>
    <li>dynamic content</li>
    <li>dynamic content</li>
    <li>dynamic content</li>
    <li>Heading</li>
    </Ul> now I wanted to wrap a container as i said above

Answer (score 0):

Make it more semantic nested lists

```
<Ul class="wrap">
  <li>heading
    <Ul>
      <li>dynamic content</li>
      <li>dynamic content</li>
      <li>dynamic content</li>
      <li>dynamic content</li>
      <li>dynamic content</li>
    </Ul>
  </li>
</Ul>
```